# How many levels are there in Grindstone?

Tags: grindstone

I can already see 120, and there seem to be more.
This is [Grindstone](http://www.capybaragames.com/Grindstone/) on [Apple Arcade](https://www.apple.com/apple-arcade/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence on the two-paragraph page you linked reads:

> 150 levels of intense puzzle-battling madness!

Answer (score 1):

Grindstone originally had 150 levels, but free updates have [increased this to 230 levels](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/grindstones-huge-new-update-adds-50-levels-and-dai/1100-6480389/) as of July 2020. A daily challenge mode was also added.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was stuck at 120 but if you tap the rock that says 120, it will cash in your crowns and you can continue.
[image]